# Average number of views per tag

Tags: support, tagging, statistics

Is it a simple query to find out the average number of views for all questions with a given tag? If so, I'm curious which tags have the highest average views and the lowest average views.

Comment: I suspect there is a strong correlation to the specificity (is that even a word?) and to the complexity of the topic described by the tag.

Comment: One expert that sees your question and posts an answer is worth 10,000 views that contribute zero answers. Are you here for the answers, or are you here for the votes? :-) (I'm not insinuating or anything!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Soon, the views will mean the number of [people you helped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244261/259867) (including the views of questions asked.)

Comment: @Raff: Then, in more way than one, we could say that people with very high pH are those which have strong basic (and low acidity!).

Comment: (Also, @Raff, according to [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/251652/people-helped-aka-ph-not-guaranteed-work-in-progress), I have helped over 1.6M people. That doesn't sound right.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's not supposed to be right, it's supposed to give you warm fuzzies. Does it?

Comment: @Warm Fuzzies: No, it doesn't. If I want a fuzzy warmth, I just get under the fuzzy microfiber blanket we have here at home. If it's really cold, I have an excellent duvet to put on me as well. If I want a really deep sense of warm fuzziness, I drink some good scotch, and let biochemistry do the rest. This site? This site is for a whole other thing I like, it's called math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Among all tags

- Most viewed (1-5): [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), [fair-division](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fair-division), [music-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-theory), [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list), [hardware](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware)
- Least viewed (1-5 from the bottom): [semialgebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semialgebras), [gamma-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-distribution), [grammar-extraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-extraction), [maximal-subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maximal-subgroup), [schauder-basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schauder-basis)

#### Among the tags with at least 1000 questions

- Most viewed: [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education), [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question), [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle), [recreational-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-mathematics)
- Least viewed: [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification), [lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebras), [sobolev-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sobolev-spaces), [operator-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operator-theory), [modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) tied with [representation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theory)

[Complete list](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/253864/tags-by-average-number-of-views-per-post)

Comment: Thanks! I like that you can sort your results by clicking on the column headings. It's also reassuring that the tag with the most questions is 'calculus'.